# Define Keybinding to insert special character in VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code

I would like to define a keybinding to insert a specific unicode character in VSCode. What is the right way to achieve this ?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

VSCode has a `type` command to handle exactly this kind of use case:

In `keybindings.json`:

```
{
    "key": "ctrl+alt+1 s",
    "command": "type",
    "args": {
        "text": "Ψ"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Type and select "**Preferences: Open Keyboard Shortcuts (JSON)**" in the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> menu in VSCode.

The file **is** called `keybindings.json` but it doesn't seem to be indexed quite as such in search for some reason.